# Finding a limit with a Square Root

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{9x^6-x}}{x^3+7}$$

I thought it would simply be $1/3$, not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: To start: divide top and bottom by $x^3$.

Comment: I saw the limit at $-\infty$ before the edit.

Comment: @Sami Look at the review history; there was never any $-\infty$, but the OPs original post could have easily been misunderstood.

Comment: @amWhy This's what the OP wrote:

as lim -> -infinity (sqrt(9x^6-x))/(x^3+7)

Comment: Anyway thank you @amWhy I learned the use of the *cancel* command from one of you post and I tried use it in my answer here;-)

Comment: I see! Plus you used overbracing!

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{9x^6 - x}}{x^3 + 7}\quad = \quad\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{9 - \frac{1}{x^5}}}{1 + \frac 7{x^3}} = \frac {\sqrt{9 - 0}}{1 + 0} = \sqrt 9 = 3$$

I divided the numerator and denominator by $x^3$.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$x=_\infty o(x^6)\quad;\quad 7=_\infty o(x^3)$$
then we can write
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{9x^6-x}}{x^3+7}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{9x^6\cancel{-x}}}{x^3\cancel{+7}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\overbrace{-3x^3}^{\ge0}}{x^3}=-3$$

Comment: The original post had $\;-\infty\;$ in the limit. This answer correctly addresses that. +1